# How create a test function on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to create custom functions on wordpress ? the test function is bellow

```
function test() {

    echo "Welcome";
}
```

and how can we convert this function to wordpress and how we can call this function?

Comment: Define this function in `functions.php` and you can call this function from anywhere inside your wordpress files.

Comment: you just need to call the function like test();

Answer (score 1):

Put it in `functions.php` in your theme. You can then call the function from anywhere in your theme. You can have the function only be called on certain events by adding it as an action to a hook.

For example this would call the function whenever you save a post:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'test' );
```

[See the list of action hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Answer (score 1):

add your function in your theme functions.php

```
function test() {

    echo "Welcome";
}
add_action('init','test');
```

for more details refer  [codex action hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)